# External K Way Merge. Iterator with integer streams

Tags: java, file, iterator, java-stream

Iterator doesnt work as expected.

This is k way merging algorithm

We have big input file (1024 bytes for test) with random generated integer numbers, and this file is divided in n-smaller chunks, which size is 256 bytes (for test), numbers in chunks is already sorted.
Then each file is transformed into a `Stream<Integer>`, and each stream has own iterator, each iterator has own integer value. `Set<IteratorInfo>` consists of these iterators, has the first element as iterator with the smallest value.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.time.temporal.Temporal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class MergeFileSorter implements FileSorter {

    // number of elements
    private int chunkSize;
    private String file;

    // Number of runs to be merged
    private int numberOfRuns;

    // FileReader
    private FileSplitter fileSplitter = new FileSplitter();
    private FileReader fileReader;

    public MergeFileSorter(String file, int runs, int chunkSize) {
        this.file = file;
        this.numberOfRuns = runs;
        this.chunkSize = chunkSize;
    }

    @Override
    public void sort(String inputPath, String outPath) {
        try {
            fileSplitter.readChunks(inputPath, (int) chunkSize);
            mergeAndSort(inputPath, outPath, chunkSize);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private void mergeAndSort(String inputPath, String outPath, int chunkSize) throws IOException {
        Path chunkFolder = fileSplitter.getChunkFolder(inputPath);

        List<Path> chunks = Files.walk(chunkFolder).filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path)).toList();

        Iterator<Integer> treeSetMergedIterator = new TreeSetMergedIterator(chunks);

        Path path = Path.of(outPath);
        Files.write(path, new byte[0]);
        int intCount = 0;

        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();

        int index = 0;
        while (treeSetMergedIterator.hasNext()){
           // System.out.println("Int Count: " + (++intCount));
            Integer value = treeSetMergedIterator.next();
            integers.add(value);

            if (integers.size() >= chunkSize/Integer.BYTES){
                Files.write(path, convertIntegersToByteArray(integers), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                integers.clear();
            }
        }
        if (!integers.isEmpty()){
            Files.write(path, convertIntegersToByteArray(integers), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }
    }

    public static List<String> convertIntegersToStrings(List<Integer> integerList) {
        return integerList.stream()
                .map(Object::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static List<String> convertIntegersToStrings(int[] integerList) {
        return Arrays.stream(integerList)  // Stream the array
                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)  // Convert each integer to a string
                .collect(Collectors.toList());  //
    }

    public static byte[] convertIntegersToByteArray(List<Integer> integers) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(integers.size()*Integer.BYTES);
        for (Integer integer : integers) {
            buffer.putInt(integer);
        }
        return buffer.array();
    }

    public static byte[] convertIntegersToByteArray(int[] integers) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(integers.length * Integer.BYTES);
        for (int integer : integers) {
            buffer.putInt(integer);
        }
        return buffer.array();
    }
}
```

This loop adds iterators' values to `Integer` array and writes it to output file with sorted chunks.

Problem is that output file's size isn't the same as size of inputfile, and always varies (400-500 bytes) and if chunk is 4 bytes (smaller) the output file can be up to 1000 bytes.

When i read 32 byte file and smaller (and chunk's size is 32/16/8/4), everything works fine. Reading files in `treeMergedIterator` seems correct as buffer's size is always full and matches the size of chunk file.

But `treeSetMergedIterator.hasNext()` always unexpectedly returns `false` and algorithm stops working, but there are numbers left.

All methods converting bytes to int or int to bytes seem correct.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class TreeSetMergedIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private final Set<IteratorInfo> iterators;

    public TreeSetMergedIterator(List<Path> paths) {
        iterators = paths.stream()
                .map(this::streamLines)
                .map(Stream::iterator)
                .map(IteratorInfo::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
    }

    private Stream<Integer> streamLines(Path path) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            return bytesToIntList(bytes).stream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterators.stream().anyMatch(iteratorInfo -> {
            if (iteratorInfo.getIterator().hasNext()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return iteratorInfo.value != null;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        IteratorInfo info = iterators.iterator().next();
        Integer value = info.value;
        iterators.remove(info);
        if (info.iterator.hasNext()) {
            iterators.add(info.next());
        }

        return value;
    }

    private List<Integer> bytesToIntList(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
        /* int[] integers = new int[buffer.capacity()/Integer.BYTES];*/
        while (buffer.remaining() >= 4) {
            integers.add(buffer.getInt());
        }
        /* while (buffer.hasRemaining()){
            integers[buffer.position()/Integer.BYTES] = buffer.getInt();
        }*/
        return integers;
    }

    static class IteratorInfo implements Comparable<IteratorInfo> {

        private final Iterator<Integer> iterator;

        private Integer value;

        public IteratorInfo(Iterator<Integer> iterator) {
            this.iterator = iterator;
            value = iterator.next();
        }

        public IteratorInfo next() {
            value = iterator.next();
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(IteratorInfo info) {
            return Integer.compare(value, info.value);
        }

        public Iterator<Integer> getIterator() {
            return iterator;
        }
    }
}
```

I have also implemented easier implementation (`MergedIterator` class) with array of iterators instead of set, but the problem still the same.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MergedIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    private final List<Iterator<Integer>> iterators;

    private final Integer[] currentData;

    public MergedIterator(List<Path> paths) {
        iterators = paths.stream()
                .map(this::streamLines)
                .map(Stream::iterator)
                .toList();
        currentData = iterators.stream()
                .map(Iterator::next)
                .toArray(Integer[]::new);
    }

    private Stream<Integer> streamLines(Path path) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            return bytesToIntList(bytes).stream();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return iterators.stream().anyMatch(Iterator::hasNext);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int minIndex = -1;

        for (int i = 0; i < currentData.length; i++) {
            if (currentData[i] != null && currentData[i] < minValue) {
                minValue = currentData[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }

        Iterator<Integer> minIterator = iterators.get(minIndex);
        currentData[minIndex] = minIterator.hasNext() ? minIterator.next() : null;

        return minValue;
    }

    private List<Integer> bytesToIntList(byte[] bytes) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes);
        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
      
        while (buffer.remaining() >= 4) {
            integers.add(buffer.getInt());
        }
        
        return integers;
    }
}
```

The JVM memory heap is 100 Mib

Here is main class: (number of runs don't take into account)

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {

    public static final long GENERATED_FILE_SIZE = 1024;

    public static final int chunkSize = 256;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filePath = "random_file.dat";
        String resultPath = "result.dat";

        FileGenerator fileGenerator = new FileGenerator();
        fileGenerator.generateRandomFile(filePath, GENERATED_FILE_SIZE, chunkSize);

        MergeFileSorter fileSorter = new MergeFileSorter(filePath, 2,  chunkSize);
        fileSorter.sort(filePath, resultPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your `FileSplitter` do? For now it looks like it is completely useless - but maybe it has side-effects that contribute to the problem or the solution?

Comment: It splits big file into smaller chunks and sort them, it works fine

Comment: @cyberbrain I track possible data loss until reaching 'map(Stream::iterator).map(IteratorInfo::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));'
Stream<Integer> contains 64 integers 4 times as expected.

Comment: i tracked that iterator having a value returns false in hasNext() method unexpectedly.

Comment: Are you aware that a set has each value only once? So if your input data contains a value multiple times, the map will contain it only once.

Comment: @cyberbrain hell no, i changed my number generation, so it generates just in descending order now, and the output file just misses one int. It's 1020 bytes, or if the input one is 2048, the output is 2044 bytes

Comment: And does it miss the last value or anything from the beginning or middle?

Comment: Your real problem could be that in the constructor of `TreeSetMergedIterator.IteratorInfo` you initialize the value `value = iterator.next();`. So the first call to an iterator is not "secured" with `iterator.hasNext()`, and you will "loose" one value in combination of the `TreeSetMergedIterator.IteratorInfo.next()` method and the `iterator.hasNext()`.

Comment: @cyberbrain the last one

Comment: how to achieve a stream containing duplicate values?

Comment: `while (buffer.remaining() >= 4) {` what about bytes array less than 4? considering line breaks etc

Answer (score 0):

For now I can only give general advice how to track the bug:

You shoudld split File reading, File writing and sorting into three independent parts. If this seems not practical due to large file sizes, you could still have a source that reads the next piece of input on request and a sink that write a piece of output on request. This way you can test the three parts individually.

Also you should not use random data for testing, but well defined ones. You can generate the test data files once randomly, but then you should reuse them. This way you can also provide an expected outcome and determine results of a test automatically.

And finally: did you test your code with data that doesn't have to be sorted at all? So you could find out better, where the error happens. Also I would write test that

1. read a known file and compare it to hardcoded expected data
2. write hardcoded data and compare it to a well known file
3. read a known file and compare it to a well known expected file

All three cases should not involve any sorting (you could implement dummy-sort, that just passes the data through).